# Fatal error: Class 'Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234

Tags: wordpress

After installing Fishpig via Magento Connect I got the following error I'm racking my brains over trying to figure out how to resolve, any ideas?

Fatal error: Class 'Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234

Thanks.

Comment: Try log out your admin section and login again..remove cache..

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to compilation being enabled on your production environment, but that file has not been 'compiled' (copied to includes/src).

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the include warning, it seems like you have the compiler enabled but it cannot find the (flattened) file.

So either disable the compiler:

php shell/compiler.php disable
Or run a compilation so that it will generate the file for you:

php shell/compiler.php compile